# How to get more information out of the Ocaml Compiler

Tags: compiler-errors, syntax-error, ocaml

I have been having the hardest time with `ocamlc`, and it's extremely uninformative error messages. Right now, when I compile one of my files, it gives me

```
Error: Syntax Error
```

on the last line of the file, which is empty. So, I'm assuming I'm missing some open parenthesis or something, I'm not sure. Regardless, how do people who use Ocaml in a production setting deal with this? Are there any available tools that give any hint at all as to what character the lexer was expecting, or just better error messages in general?

Specifically, I'm looking for a tool like [this](https://github.com/reasonml-old/BetterErrors), which looks awesome. But it looks like it's no longer under development, however this looks like a tool that compiles Ocaml to Javascript, which isn't the end result that I want.

Any suggestions as to how people usually resolve Ocaml syntax errors would be great.

Comment: I don't use ocamlc directly, but there should at least be some location information. Are you sure there isn't?

Comment: Btw, BetterErrors has been superseeded by "super errors", which is baked into BuckleScript and the slightly modified compiler it uses. There's been some effort to upstream it I think, but these things tend to take some time (which isn't necessarily a bad thing in the long term).

Comment: @glennsl There's definitely "location information", but in my current case, the location is pointing to the last line of the file at characters 0-0. And the last 40 lines of the file are *only comments*. BuckleScript seems a bit "too heavy" of a tool. I just want a slightly better error-reporting system, not a whole build system which JS integration/cross compilation/etc.

Comment: If the location information is bad, there's probably not much an "add-on" like BetterErrors or super errors can do. You might have to rework the entire parser, or even change the syntax to have more bulkheads that contain syntax errors. The problem is likely that, on a syntactic level, there simply is no error until it gets to the end and notice something is missing (probably an unclosed parenthesis or something). If you think it's hard to track down the cause of errors like that, imagine being a compiler that doesn't even understand what you're trying to do!

Comment: Well I can definitely agree with that. But like, maybe if it told me what it was expecting, as I've seen with the clang/GNU compilers. Idk, maybe I'm asking for too much :/ regardless, Surely no company that uses Ocaml in production uses these barebones error messages.

Comment: @EnricoBorba people only get the barebones 'syntax error' messages while they're still learning the basics. Rather than put a lot of effort into improving these kinds of error messages so that *you* can benefit from them (I'd agree that it would be beneficial to other people if you spent that time), it would be quicker to correct the syntax errors and move on.

Comment: no, you're not "missing open parentheses or something". You're mixing toplevel and non-toplevel let forms.

Comment: Almost of all the professional OCaml programmers are just happy with the current vanilla syntax errors.  You can avoid lots of errors by using an auto-indentation tool like ocp-indent regularly to check how your code is actually parsed.

Comment: Omg yes. Im guessing that most people give up on OCaml due to the unfriendly compiler errors

Answer (score 3):

Given one.ml:

```
let a = 42 in
let f x = x + a
let g x = x + x
```

You'll get this error when compiling it:

```
$ ocamlc one.ml 
File "one.ml", line 3, characters 0-3:
Error: Syntax error
```

ocamlc gives up on making sense of this at the `let` on the third line, because at that point the only possible continuation of line 2 is `in` and another expression (or a continuation of `x + x`, like `+ x in ...`). The fundamental problem here is that ocamlc didn't throw an error at the end of line 1, because ocamlc tries to allow both *proper OCaml* and a mess of expressions that you could have pasted into an interactive session. It even allows `;;` in files, which is absurd: `;;` is only needed interactively because without some extraordinary termination rule (like Python's blank empty line that ends a definition - but only interactively) OCaml can't know that an expression isn't to be continued by an operator and another expression. ocamlc is trying to be forgiving of confusion to the point that confusions are prolonged, instead of corrected.

So what is proper OCaml? For whatever reason it's not documented well. But you can get a feel for it very quickly when you understand that some forms you can put 'leftmost' in a file and some form can only exist as subexpressions of the first form, or if you try to read well-written OCaml while remembering that whitespace is insignificant in OCaml in the same manner as in C: OCaml isn't using the blank lines you between definitions to understand that those definitions are separate, so how is it separating them?

Or, you can start with a few rules. "Don't use `let ... in` except as a subexpression." "Don't try to perform side effects except as subexpressions of `let () =`", "Treat semicolons like operators that require a right-hand side, not terminators", etc.

So instead of one.ml, any of these would work:

```
let a = 42
let f x = x + a
let g x = x + x
```

or

```
let f x =
  let a = 42 in
  x + a
let g x = x + x
```

or (obviously this is bad style):

```
let f x = let a = 42 in x + a let g x = x + x
```

two.ml has the other common error:

```
let () =
  print_endline "hi";

let f x = x + x
```

You'll get a 'Syntax error' on line 5, characters 0=0. Which is ocamlc reaching the end of the file and still not seeing the `in` (or a continuation of `x + x`) that must follow. Because the `;` on line 2 means that the `let` on line 4 must be a subexpression of the `let` on line 1.

Instead of two.ml, any of these would be fine:

```
let () =
  print_endline "hi"

let f x = x + x
```

or (again bad style, but imagine it with the semicolon):

```
let () = print_endline "hi" let f x = x + x
```

Although you can also get a 'bare' syntax error with `let x = [| ]`, even someone very new to OCaml will recognize such errors the moment they find the line and character range complained about, so such errors aren't frustrating at the level of one.ml and two.ml